# Unable to refresh the list view in realtime after deleting an item from the list

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am having a list view with text and a button. The contents of the listview(the text) are fetched from the SQLite database. I have implemented the code such that, if anyone clicks the button, the corresponding flag of that list item changes in the database table. My intention would be, as soon as the flag is changed in the database table, the corresponding list item should disappear from the list.

Currently, I'm able to change the flag value for the list item (successfully updating in the corresponding column of the table), but the list item remains in the list view until I re-open the app. The list item then disappears as desired.

Is there a way such that as soon as I click the button, and as the flag value is changed at the background, the list refreshes and show me only other items of the list.?

Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the Item that is being deleted from database is also deleting from list?

Comment: build ContenProvider and use CursorLoader from v4 compat lib(look at sdk samples) ... you should use getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(...) in your update/insert/delete implementation of ContentProvider and refresh stuff will be done in CursorLoader(registering for change and requery) automaticly ... that's the "android way" ... you can even not use CursorLoader ... it will be done automaticly with deprecated requery ... so the only code that you need to write is ContentProvider

Comment: ... don't forget to add return_cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri) in query implementation of your ContentProvider ... (see NotePad sample in your sdk folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your responses. I have tried to do it in android way, but seems to be a bit complex. Hence inorder to refresh the list view after updating the list I have re-called the activity using intents so that I'll get a fresh list view with added or deleted list entries.

Hope I'll find other android way of solutions soon.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a [requery()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#requery%28%29) after changing anything in data source.

-- Edit --

Just found that requery is deprecating, but anyway, the idea is the same. Query for another new Cursor, and set it in CursorAdapter (if you are using it).

Answer (score 0):

1. Query with a new Cursor and set the results in the CursorAdapter
2. invalidate() the existing list view

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for a ListView, you have to prepare an adapter for the ListView to provide the content of every item in the ListView.
The basic idea is that in order to refresh the listview, you have to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to request the refreshment.

Answer (score 0):

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
```